# F-Distribution formula

Tags: distributions, inference, f-distribution

How did we get this formula? Can you explain it with visualization if possible?

> $$\text{Using properties of f distribution } f_{(1-\alpha), (\nu_1,\nu_2)} = \frac 1 {f_{\alpha, (\nu_2,\nu_1)}}$$

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thanks! Can I assume that the area under the curve and starting from the point (a) on the f-axis is f(a, v1, v2) "the ratio of the first chi-distrib.over the second distrib." and the area before this line is the inverse? like f(1-a, v2, v1)? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  You have one typographical error however "cure" should be "curve".

Comment: I will change my comment to an answer as Gung has suggested.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thank you, I corrected It. Yeah, It'll be great!

Comment: It's *not* a ratio of chi-square distributions (indeed a ratio of distribution functions is not itself a distribution in general). It's not even  the distribution of a ratio of two independent chi square random variables. It's the distribution of a ratio of two independent chi square random variables, *each of which has been divided by its degrees of freedom*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The F distribution is the ratio of two independent chi-square distributions divided by the numerator and denominator degrees of freedom as given.  So flipping the numerator reverses the tails of the distribution as expressed in the equation you have exhibited.  I think you can visualize this without pictures of these two F distributions.